# iOS Paypal MPL developer error

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

My PayPal MPL integration which has been working correctly, stopped working today. My initial prototype which has had no code changes done to it has also stopped working.

I have seen similar questions asked on here but none solved my problem.

I upgraded to the new 1.6 MPL but it gives the same error.

```
Checking Error********************
Posting Error: 2147483647
DEVELOPER ERROR: This app not using a supported version of the PayPal library.
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

I'm running Xcode 4.5 and this occurs in both iOS 5 & 6

Comment: we have the same issue, except we didn't upgraded anything. It was working yesterday (and for the past 6months), and suddenly it doesn't work anymore, and we have the same error as you...

Comment: Same here
It seems something happened in PayPal servers.
Though it looks like a sandbox issue only

Comment: I figured it might only a sandbox issue, but I didn't have a live account yet to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks - this is now resolved. Please download the updated libraries from X.com: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index?qt-paypal_sdk_index=2#qt-paypal_sdk_index

Comment: It's been working for the last few days but it just stopped again a few hours ago. Same error.

Comment: it should be working again - the change got overwritten - this time we added monitors to make sure it won't happen again. Sorry about that.

Comment: It stopped again Today - using the lastest library -
Posting Error: 2147483647
DEVELOPER ERROR: This app not using a supported version of the PayPal library.

Comment: @Praveen Can you help on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702860/paypal-sandbox-is-not-working-for-non-us-developers-using-paypal-ios-sdk This happens me after new REST API is released

Comment: @Praveen can you help me regarding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040297/paypal-mpl-login-button-disabled-on-device thanks in advance

Comment: @Praveen it stopped. i got error message Posting Error: 2147483647. please help me. thnx